# Why does merging unequally matched rows not work on local dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas `data`frame with questions (`type = 1`) and answers (`type = 2`). col `section_id` and `type` are integer. all other col are string. I want to merge the "answer rows" with their corresponding "question rows" (equal values in `section_id`) before appending some of the answer rows'  values as extra columns (`Ans`, `ans_t`) to their corresponding "question rows".

```
c = ['pos', 'Ans', 'Q_ID', 'leg', 'que_l', 'ans_l', 'par', 'ans_f', 'que_date', 'ask', 'M_ID', 'part', 'area', 'que_t', 'ans_t', 'ISO', 'con', 'id', 'section_id', 'type', 'dep', 'off']
d = [[None, None, '16-17/1/2017-11-15/1', '16-17', '14.0', None, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-11-20', 'Peter Muller', '41749', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', None, 'eee', 'fff', '111865.q2', 24339851, 1, None, None],
     [None, None, '16-17/24/17-11-09/1', '16-17', '28.0', None, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-11-20', 'Peter Muller', '41749', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ppp', None, 'eee', 'fff', '111867.q1', 24339851, 1, None, None],
     [None, None, '16-17/73/17-10-09/1', '16-17', '69.0', None, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-11-20', 'Peter Muller', '41749', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'lll', None, 'eee', 'fff', '111863.r0', 24339851, 1, None, None],
     ['erg', 'wer', '16-17/42/16-10-09/1', '16-17', None, 67.0, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-11-20', None, '46753', 'bbb', 'ccc', None, 'ttt', 'eee', 'asd', '111863.r0', 24339851, 2, None, None],
     [None, None, '16-17/12/16-12-08/1', '16-17', '37.0', None, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-10-10', 'Peter Muller', '41749', 'bbb', 'qqq', 'rrr', None, 'eee', 'fff', '108143.r0', 24303320, 1, None, None],
     ['erg', 'wer', '16-17/12/16-12-07/1', '16-17', None, 64.0, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-10-10', None, '46753', 'bbb', 'qqq', None, 'uuu', 'eee', 'asd', '108143.r0', 24303320, 2, None, None],
     [None, None, '16-17/77/16-12-04/1', '16-17', '46.0', None, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-10-08', 'Markus John', '34567', 'ztr', 'yyy', 'nnn', None, 'eee', 'www', '127193.q0', 10343145, 1, None, None],
     ['qwe', 'wer', '16-17/37/17-11-07/1', '16-17', None, 60.0, 'aaa', 'hhh', '2016-12-12', None, '19745', 'bbb', 'gtt', None, 'ooo', 'eee', 'asd', '906213.r0', 23222978, 2, None, None]]
data = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
data.loc[data['type'] == 2, 'Ans.1'] = data['Ans']
data.loc[data['type'] == 2, 'ans_t.1'] = data['ans_t']
my_cols = ['que_t','ans_t','Ans','ans_t','Ans.1','ans_t.1']
data[my_cols] = data.sort_values(['section_id','type']).groupby('section_id')[my_cols].transform(lambda x: x.bfill())
data.dropna(subset=['que_t'],inplace=True)
data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
print(data)
```

The code works fine on the minimal reproducible example. Unfortunately the dataset is too large to account for every detail, which is why this example may not necessarily be representative.

**Problem:** When i run the code on the actual dataset, nothing gets merged, even though i manually checked for `section_id` duplicates

Before executing the code, i remove empty cells from the dataset

```
data.where(pd.notnull(data), None)
data.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

which doesent solve the problem

**Question:** How do i need to adjust my code in order to account for details (e.g. encoding, formats, ..) in the dataset that could cause it not to merge?

**Appendix:**

Someone told me to remove data from the dataset gradually, checking each time that the testcase is still reproducible. If some removal results in the testcase not working then reinstate it and remove something else instead. When there's absolutely nothing that can be removed, you have your minimal data set.

Someone else said i should apply a parsing function to parse the data. Didnt help

```
def parse(x):
try:
    return int(x)
except ValueError:
    return np.nan
data['que_t'] = data['que_t'].apply(parse)
data['ans_t'] = data['ans_t'].apply(parse)
data.dtypes
```

Or should I search for non-number string and replace when with `NaN` ?

```
replaced_with_nan = data['col_name'].replace(re.compile('\D+'), np.nan)
data['col_name'] = replaced_with_nan.astype(np.float)
```

Here is another approach which like the answer from Andrej Kesely returns an empty dataframe when used on the actual dataframe

```
df1 = data.loc[df.type == 1].copy()
df2 = data.loc[df.type == 2].copy()
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='section_id', how='outer')
merged_df = merged_df.loc[:,['section_id','que_t_x','ans_t_y','Ans_x','Ans_y']]
merged_df.rename(columns={'que_t_x':'que_t','ans_t_y':'ans_t','Ans_x':'Ans','Ans_y':'Ans.1'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible Check the line `data[my_cols] = data.sort_values(...`

Comment: Hello. It is reproducible. And it works. Not on the acutal dataset though.

Comment: @id345678 Your code in the problem description has a bug so that it is not reproducible. The bug is in the line: my_cols = ['que_t','ans_t','Ans','ans_t','Ans.1','ans_t.1']. There are two `ans_t`s, which causes an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understand you correctly, you can filter the dataframe and do `.merge`:

```py
x = (
    df[df["que/ans"] == 1]
    .merge(
        df[df["que/ans"] == 2],
        on="section_id",
        how="outer",
        suffixes=("_que", "_ans"),
    )
    .drop(columns=["ans_t_que", "name_que", "ans_len_que", "que_t_ans"])
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   que/ans_que  section_id que_t_que  date_que part_que  que/ans_ans ans_t_ans name_ans  date_ans part_ans  ans_len_ans
0            1         444    qtext1       456      bbb          2.0    atext2   Markus     654.0      eee         64.0
1            1         444    qtext3       987      ddd          2.0    atext2   Markus     654.0      eee         64.0
2            1         123    qtext2       789      ccc          2.0    atext1     Alex     123.0      aaa         78.0
3            1         555    qtext4       321      fff          NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN          NaN
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I see what you did there but receive an empty dataframe that should actually have around 5000 rows after merging. From the name of the columns i think you understood me correctly and that also works but I suspect the problem is that some cells are not actually NaN but None or "empty"? Also, there is a date column that is not in datetime but object dtype. May that cause the problem? I updated my question to give a debug log

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading your data from csv or excel, I would recommend you to define the dtype during reading. This is to ensure that the keys you use to merge did not have any data loss.

Example:
section_id = 00001234
After reading from csv, it could just be 1234.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype={'section_id' = str})
```

Hope this will solve your merging issue.

Comment: i retrieve it from json files and tried it by ensuring string type before merging but didnt help. thanks for your idea though :)

Comment: @id345678 since you think that NaN or "empty" causes the problem, why don't you try fillna(-999) before doing the merge and fix the code from there? From Andrej Kesely codes, it will provide you the rows which not merging well, it is a good start to check the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your last solution following Andrej's answer seems to be working. However, there are some missing context regarding `df` variable. In addition, all the strings reflecting emptiness is replaced with `np.nan`. Thus I rewrote it to `data` as follows:

```
data.replace(['', 'None', 'nan', None], np.nan, inplace=True)
df1 = data.loc[data.type == 1].copy()
df2 = data.loc[data.type == 2].copy()
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='section_id', how='outer')
merged_df = merged_df[['section_id','que_t_x','ans_t_y','Ans_x','Ans_y']]
merged_df.rename(columns={'que_t_x':'que_t','ans_t_y':'ans_t','Ans_x':'Ans','Ans_y':'Ans.1'}, inplace=True)
print(merged_df)
```